# PUG- Cannot indent items in panel-body when iterating

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to create a panel for a group of items that contains elements:

Sample data:

```
mid |      mdescription       | mgdescription  
-----+-------------------------+----------------
18 | Goods Issued Notes      | Stores
15 | In Stock Items          | Stores
17 | Import from Excel       | Stores
 2 | Owned Equipment         | Equipment
 9 | Equipment Models        | Equipment
 3 | Menu Items Setup        | System Setup
11 | Menu Groups             | System Setup
 1 | Users Setup             | System Setup
16 | Maintenance Summaries   | Workshop
12 | Maintenance Requests    | Workshop
```

Basically I need a panel that displays the mgdescription as header and then insert the relative mdescription in the panel body.

PUG Template:

```
- var oldmenu = "";
div.row
    each p in menu
        - if ( p.mgdescription != oldmenu )
            div.panel.panel-default
                div.panel-heading
                    span.bold.underline Menu Group: #{p.mgdescription}
                div.panel-body
                    input.perms(type="checkbox" id="menu_" + p.mid)
                    label(for="menu_" + p.mid) &nbsp;#{p.mdescription}
            - oldmenu = p.mgdescription;
        - else          
            input.perms(type="checkbox" id="menu_" + p.mid)
            label(for="menu_" + p.mid) &nbsp;#{p.mdescription}
```

The panel is created correctly and the header if fine. The first mdescriptionis part of the panel. The problem are the other mdescriptions as they appear out of the panel-body. I have tried indenting but it does not seem to work. What solution do I have to this?

Comment: Could you post a picture of the panel as it currently looks?

Comment: Are you trying to make it so that all `mdescriptions` under the same  `mgdescription` are posted together? Like `Owned Equipment` and `Equipment Models` are under the same `Equipment` header?

Comment: Yes. Actually sorted it out with a mixin. Should I answer myself the question?

Comment: Yes, @FabrizioMazzoni

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the issue by using a mixin:

```
mixin permline(mid, description)
    div.col-md-3.text-left
        input.perms(type="checkbox" name="menu_" + mid  id="menu_" + mid)
        label(for="menu_" + mid) &nbsp;#{description}

each p in menu
    - if ( p.mgdescription != oldmenu )
        - oldmenu = p.mgdescription;
        div.panel.panel-info
            div.panel-heading
                span.underline #{p.mgdescription}
            div.panel-body
                div.row
                each i in menu
                    - if ( i.mgdescription == p.mgdescription )
                        +permline(i.mid, i.mdescription)
```